# Connection to RDP from Excel

Tags: excel, rdp, vba

I see many forums talking about starting Remote Desktop Connection from Excel file.

I also saw this code, which is fine and works.

```
Sub OpenRDP()
Dim MyRDP As Variant

MyLink = "c:\windows\system32\mstsc.exe /v:" & ActiveCell.Value

MyRDP = Shell(MyLink, 1)

End Sub
```

However, in my Excel file, in one column I have HOST address, and next to it is a column with passwords.

My question is: is it possible to start RDP and pass to it host IP address and password? If it is, how is it done?

thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you are just calling a command through the shell, you don't really have a handle on the application that is launching programatically (RDP in this case). So you can't do something like:

```
MyRDP.Password = Range("B2").value
```

You can, however, use `Application.Sendkeys` to send keypresses to windows which it will blindly apply to where ever your cursor happens to be when you send the command.

Assuming your password is stored in the same row, but on column over (the adjacent cell):

```
Application.SendKeys (ActiveCell.Offset(, 1).Value & "{ENTER}")
```

Sending your password and an "Enter" keypress to accept the password.

Because RDP takes a moment to pop up, you can't just toss that line in after calling the shell command. You have to wait some amount of time. 5 seconds works nicely on my compyter, but you computer may be slower or faster so you may have to monkey around a bit here:

```
Sub OpenRDP()
    Dim MyRDP As Variant
    Dim MyLink As String

    MyLink = "c:\windows\system32\mstsc.exe /v:" & ActiveCell.Value

    MyRDP = Shell(MyLink, 1)

    'wait five seconds and send password in adjacent cell of same row
    Application.Wait (Now() + TimeValue("0:00:5"))
    Application.SendKeys (ActiveCell.Offset(, 1).Value & "{ENTER}")

End Sub
```

I have no doubt that this could be about 10000x more sophisticated by querying WMI for running processes and waiting for RDP to pop up to do the sendkeys, or hunting down a library to help interact with RDP using code, but... for two lines of code this method will get you pretty far.

Also, (because it's worth saying), storing your passwords in excel is not terribly secure. Anyone gaining access to your workbook will have access to your remote desktops. Even if the workbook is password protected, it can be cracked with the push of a button.

Comment: Also, thank you for taking the effort to explain the process and pros and cons. Really useful.